# How to know the leaving time of each car in the simulation?

Tags: omnet++, veins, traffic-simulation, sumo

I use Omnet++-4.6, sumo-0.22.0 and Veins-4a2.

In my simulation, I need to know how much time each car takes during the simulation.

So, I need to know the time which each car leaves the simulation.

How can I do this please?

Comment: Unclear, you don't provide enough information to answer the question. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit question or else this will get closed.

Comment: Aren't _departure_ time and _leaving_ time the same? Did you mean _departure and arrival_ time perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I need to know when each car leaves the simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *finalize* method in every module to execute code when the object gets destroyed (i.e. leaves the simulation). Try this in the car's application layer (e.g. *TraciDemo11p*).

Comment: and similarly, you can use the initialization method to determine the start time, because each vehicle is initialized as they are created in SUMO.